# How to add UNDO and REDO buttons to TableLayout panel in C#

Tags: c#, undo, tablelayoutpanel, redo

I'm making game where you put 8 queens on chess board so no queen attack any other. It is for my homework.
[image]

I used `TableLayoutPanel` 8x8 with `PictureBox` in every cell. They change color or picture on click and show user which one cell is available.
 But I wanted to implement Undo, so user can go step back if he does not like where he positioned his queen. I googled a lot, but every single undo-redo solution is about integers and strings, and I do not have idea how to use it for my table panel.
Do you guys have any idea how to do that? I tried to make another copy-panel and copy original one into it, before changing color happens, and if I want to undo, to actually show copy-panel but for some reason it does not work.

If it is already answered somewhere how to make undo for `TableLayoutPanel` can you please guide me to that guide?

```
  private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox picture =  (PictureBox)sender;
        //checking if cell is empty 
        if(picture.BackColor==Color.White)
        { 
            picture.Image = Properties.Resources.kraljica;

            int column = tableLayoutPanel1.GetCellPosition(picture).Column;
            int row = tableLayoutPanel1.GetCellPosition(picture).Row;

            int j = column;
            int i = row;
            //changing color of down right diagonal according to current position of queen
            while (i <= 7 && j <= 7)
            {
                tableLayoutPanel1.GetControlFromPosition(j, i).BackColor = Color.DarkRed;
                i++;
                j++;                  
            }
```

Comment: do you need undo out of box for table? i think in you case you will need to make you own undo using task pattern , because you undo more than ui - its undoing game move

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the StackOverFlow.

Normally, we'd ask you to provide some code to help us out in solving your problem, but I'll try and give you some pointers without.

You need to keep a history of past moves, in this case this would be a history of cell locations for where a queen started to where it ended up.

I suspect that you must be using an OnClick event or something similar to determine which queen is selected and where it is moved to - if not then the logic would still be the same.

You want to use the GetRow and GetColumn methods of the TableLayoutPanel control and store the result in a List control e.g.

```
public class Move
    {
      int startRow;
      int startColumn;
      int endRow;
      int endColumn;
    }
```

then in your code have properties

```
public List<Move> ListOfMoves = new List<Move>();
public SelectedMoveIndex {get;set;}
```

Everytime a new move is made add a new Move instance with populated values to the List

e.g.

```
ListOfMoves.Add(new Move(){startRow = x1, startColumn=y1, endRow=x2, endColumn=y2};
SelectedMoveIndex = ListOfMoves.Count -1;
```

where x1, y1, x2, y2 have values taken from `GetRow()` & `GetColumn()` on move start and move end.

To undo a move use the `Move` values stored at `SelectedMoveIndex` and play the backwards e.g `endRow` and `endColumn` become the start values then decrement the value of `SelectedMoveIndex`. Redo would use the values as stored at `SelectedMoveIndex` and then increment `SelectedMoveIndex` afterwards.

If you make a new move that isn't stored then you'll need to remove elements after `SelectedMoveIndex` before adding a new one.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. I edited and added part of code. I have 'onclick' 'picturebox' and 6 loops that change color of unavailable cells. Do I have to add this list moves that you explained in every loop? But, I guess then when I press undo it will undo only one cell color, not whole table setup.

Comment: You only want to keep one list, assuming that this applies to queens on the screen, otherwise it would be one per queen. So it wouldn't be stored within your OnClick event but within what I assume is a Form class that he OnClick event handler belongs to.